# How to write Azure machine learning batch scoring results to data lake?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to write the output of batch scoring into datalake:

```
    parallel_step_name = "batchscoring-" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
    
    output_dir = PipelineData(name="scores", 
                              datastore=def_ADL_store,
                              output_mode="upload",
                              output_path_on_compute="path in data lake")

parallel_run_config = ParallelRunConfig(
    environment=curated_environment,
    entry_script="use_model.py",
    source_directory="./",
    output_action="append_row",
    mini_batch_size="20",
    error_threshold=1,
    compute_target=compute_target,
    process_count_per_node=2,
    node_count=2
)
    
    batch_score_step = ParallelRunStep(
        name=parallel_step_name,
        inputs=[test_data.as_named_input("test_data")],
        output=output_dir,
        parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
        allow_reuse=False
    )
```

However I meet the error: "code": "UserError",
"message": "User program failed with Exception: Missing argument --output or its value is empty."

How can I write results of batch score to data lake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think ADLS is supported for `PipelineData`. My suggestion is to use the workspace’s default blob store for the `PipelineData`, then use a `DataTransferStep` for after the `ParallelRunStep` is completed.

Comment: output_dir = PipelineData(name="scores", 
                          datastore=datastore,
                          )
adls_data_ref = DataReference(
    datastore=def_blob_store,
    data_reference_name="adls_test_data",
    path_on_datastore="Private/Opportunities/ModelData/OneModel")
transfer_blob_to_adls = DataTransferStep(
    name="transfer_blob_to_adls",
    source_data_reference=output_dir,
    destination_data_reference=adls_data_ref,
    compute_target=data_factory_compute)

But I met the error: unexpected error: Blob contains both folder and file with same name

Comment: can you share your new `PipelineData` definition for `output_dir`?

Comment: you're very close now. here's [a thread](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/mvpforum/fr-FR/026b9b1d-6961-4217-b179-0c1973ac1fa2/data-transfer-job-failed-with-unexpected-error-systeminvalidoperationexception-blob-contains-both?forum=AzureMachineLearningService) I found with the error message you have

Comment: Thank you. I add source_reference_type: directory and succeed.

Comment: Awesome!!! Our team really loves Azure ML Pipelines, I’d love to see what you develop — especially w `ParallelRunStep`

Comment: Thanks @AndersSwanson, this answer was a life saver!  And thanks to chenxu as well, your "add source_reference_type: directory" solution really brought it all home!